# Capacitor local notification in pwa with Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

As related to this documentation :

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications

It seems possible to use Capacitor local notification plugin for the web as pwa also.

I try to push "test" a local notification every 10 seconds but nothing happen even with service worker enabled

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { LocalNotifications } = Plugins;

const notifs = await LocalNotifications.schedule({
  notifications: [
    {
      title: "Title",
      body: "Body",
      id: 1,
      schedule: {
            repeats: true,
            every: "second",
            count: 10
          },
      sound: null,
      attachments: null,
      actionTypeId: "",
      extra: null
    }
  ]
});
console.log('scheduled notifications', notifs);
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [source code](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/blob/62daefebf16ef692c291218d8ef8e78fbe0cfcd5/core/src/web/local-notifications.ts#L43) of the LocalNotification plugin for web it seems as though the notification is only scheduled if the schedule option has the "at" property.
Even then I can't get it to work on chrome for android.

Notification scheduling for PWAs is currently in trial using the [TimestampTrigger](https://web.dev/notification-triggers/) so I think the lack of browser support is the issue. Possibly getting out of trial during 2021. Just have to wait and see I guess.